# Want to create a Google Calendar Event without a Hangout/video link

Tags: google-api

I writing a Python script that will create calendar events in our company's Leaves calendar automatically when a holiday request is approved. The fundamentals are working fine but all of the events have Hangout links present in them. Since there is a Remove option on an event, it is possible to have a calendar event without a Hangout link, but it doesn't seem possible. I've tried updating an event after it has been created but if there is magic to getting the link to be removed, I can't find it.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the automatic addition of hangout links by updating the calendar settings? Not sure if this applies to new events created through the API, but here's a link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/4362302

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that seems to be across our entire domain, which isn't what I am looking for. If it only applied to a specific calendar, it would be perfect.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is by first creating an event without inviting anyone, then using the Events.patch API method to add attendees to the event. This workaround allows events to not have a google hangout link as opposed to using the Events.insert API method and passing in attendees in the body, which will create a google hangout link by default.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In this particular situation, there were never any attendees for the event. However, it looks like Google have changed the behaviour of their API. The automation to create the events in our Leaves calendar is no longer having a Hangout link added.

Comment: Ah that is great! I’m using an older version of the google api so that is why I have to rely on this method